# Matrix 2.5.3 with Assets 2.0.5 - not behaving correctly

Tags: assets, matrix, php-errors

I'm having a very bizarre issue with a fresh install of EE 2.5.5, Matrix 2.5.3 & Assets 2.0.5

I created a field group and then created a matrix field. When I did so the matrix cp did not look like it normally. Additionally when changing a cell type, none of the options change. However if I save it and reload then the options have changed to the appropriate cell type. Also on the publish page everything looks wonky.

What I've done so far, re-uploaded both assets & matrix to the site. That didn't change anything so then I re-uploaded the entire EE themes folder - still no change.

If I change the cell type to date and save I'm redirected to the CP home and have to renavigate back to custom fields. If I then change the cell type back to assets I get the following php errors.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: assets
>
> Filename: assets/ft.assets.php
>
> Line Number: 268
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /path/to/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php
>
> Line Number: 809
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /path/to/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php
>
> Line Number: 405

I'm sure the error is somehow related to not finding files correctly. I've re-uploaded everything and checked path settings and everything checks out.

[image: custom field screenshot]
[image: publish page screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation including completely reinstalling EE I found the issue.

In my config.php file I had added the following which I've used in several other sites.

```
// add-on themes path
$config['path_third_themes'] = '/path/to/public_html/addons/themes/';
$config['url_third_themes'] = '/addons/themes/';

// add-on system path
$config['third_party_path'] = '/path/to/public_html/addons/system/';
```

The issue was with url_third_themes - I've always used a relative url but I'm working on a new server this time and the new server does not like relative urls here. Once I added in the full url including http:// everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

you've posted a few problems here.  Can we focus on the Matrix issue first?

Can you delete and re-upload /themes/third_party/matrix?  Usually if you can't see some options showing up, then the issue is the themes folder.  I'm curious how much of this will fall into place if the themes are for sure fine.

Also, what FTP client are you using? And what kind of server is it? PHP, MySQL, Apache or IIS?  Those things.

Thank you!

Comment: Lisa, I already replaced both addons and the entire EE themes folder. I'm using webdrive http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html (which I use on all sites I build), but will try again using filezilla. php 5.3.17 mysql 5.1.68-cll apache 2.2.23

Comment: Sean, if that doesn't work, can you send support@pixelandtonic.com SuperAdmin and FTP details and I'll have a look? Thank you!

Comment: Lisa, have sent you an email with the credentials you requested.